# community view report via a VF page

Tags: visualforce, reporting, customer-community, limits, customer-community-plus

Could a report exposed to a SF community (Not Plus), via a VF page?
as below;

```
<apex:page id="ccs" title="Customer Case Summary" cache="false"  showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <body>
    <div>Customer Case Summary<br/>
        <apex:iframe src="00O90000009FCKe"/>

    </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

I tried this and gave the permission to the VF via profile, it is still giving me no access error, According to the documentation Customer Community Plus license can create/edit/view reports, I just need to confirm that there is no way to view a salesforce reports with Customer Community license if it is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Customer Community licenses are not able to run reports. 
See this page for more details:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm